# Is it possible to setup my own local IdentityServer instance

Tags: identityserver4

Just as the question... Is possible to create a local instance of IdentityServer?
Thing is I have disconnected clients who needs such auth method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install it locally. Its just a regular HTTP/HTTPS service, that can be placed anywhere.

Comment: Can you provide a link, please?

Comment: You find the documentation here that is very good.  https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html